# Enviar mensaje a varios números de telefónicos con AWS NSN

Tags: java, aws, sms

Estoy probando el siguiente código JAVA que envía un SMS a un solo numero de teléfono. Alguien me podría ayudar a como hacerlo  para que envié el SMS a varios destinatarios. Muchas gracias.

```
import com.amazonaws.auth.AWSCredentials;
import com.amazonaws.auth.BasicAWSCredentials;
import com.amazonaws.services.sns.AmazonSNS;
import com.amazonaws.services.sns.AmazonSNSClient;
import com.amazonaws.services.sns.AmazonSNSClientBuilder;
import com.amazonaws.services.sns.model.MessageAttributeValue;
import com.amazonaws.services.sns.model.PublishRequest;
import com.amazonaws.services.sns.model.PublishResult;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Optional;


public class Send {


public static void main(String[] args) {
    AmazonSNS snsClient = AmazonSNSClientBuilder.defaultClient();
    String message = "My SMS message";
    String phoneNumber = "+54911XXXX";
    //List<String> phoneNumber = new ArrayList<String>();

    //phoneNumber.add("+54911XXXXXXXX");
    //phoneNumber.add("+541195XXXXXXX");

    Map<String, MessageAttributeValue> smsAttributes = new HashMap<String, MessageAttributeValue>();

    sendSMSMessage(snsClient, message, phoneNumber, smsAttributes);
}

private static void sendSMSMessage(AmazonSNS snsClient, String message, String phoneNumber,
        Map<String, MessageAttributeValue> smsAttributes) {

    PublishResult result = snsClient.publish(new PublishRequest()
            .withMessage(message)
            .withPhoneNumber(phoneNumber)
            .withMessageAttributes(smsAttributes));
    System.out.println(result); //Imprimo ID.

}
```

}

Comment: Hola. ¿De dónde planeas obtener los números a usar? ¿Qué has intentado para cumplir ese nuevo requerimiento?

Comment: Gracias por responder @Alfabravo. Los numeros los voy a obtener de un JSON. Hice una prueba con ese codigo y envia SMS a un numero, pero tipo de variable de phonenumber de el SDK  AWS es String. Gracias

Comment: Puedes procesar el JSON y recorrer la estructura en la que guardes los números obtenidos con algún ciclo, invocando el envío de SMS para cada número.